# NuGet Package MySql.Data is not compatible UWP 10.0.10586

Tags: mysql, uwp, nuget

Seems like MySql.Data Package is not compatible with Windows 10 Novermber Update (10.0; Build 10586).

In order to run my application on emulators, I need to set minimum target to Windows 10 Novermber Update. But I need mysql connections too. What can I do?

```
Package MySql.Data 8.0.11 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586)
```

**EDIT:**
So I tried to install old version of Mysql.Data (6.10.6). It successfully installed but now, when I try to connect to Mysql database it gives this error below:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

```
connString = "*********";

mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString);

cmd = mcon.CreateCommand();

mcon.Open();//error happens at this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the NuGet [MySql.Data 6.10.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.10.6) Dependencies, it requires .NETStandard 2.0 witch is only supported in UWP app version 16299 now (see [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)), so if you want to use this NuGet in UWP app, you should set both your app target version and min version on Fall Creators Update build 16299.

So as the [MySql.Data 8.0.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/8.0.11), you also need to set both your app target version and min version on Fall Creators Update build 16299.